# Change pager text

Tags: 6, theming, paging

I need to change the text that appears in pagers (first/previous/next/last).  I would really prefer to not get into the overhead (and sloppiness IMO) of a string override module.

Pager.inc seems extremely themable, but man is it strangely designed ...

This is as far as I got -- in template.php:

```
function phptemplate_pager_first($text, $limit, $element=0, $parameters=array()) {
    return theme_pager_first('« Oldest', $limit, $element, $parameters);
}

function phptemplate_pager_previous($text, $limit, $element=0, $interval=1, $parameters=array()) {
    if (is_numeric($text)) {
        return theme_pager_previous($text, $limit, $element, $interval, $parameters);
    } else {
        return theme_pager_previous('‹ Older', $limit, $element, $interval, $parameters);
    }
}

function phptemplate_pager_next($text, $limit, $element=0, $interval=1, $parameters=array()) {
    if (is_numeric($text)) {
        return theme_pager_next($text, $limit, $element, $interval, $parameters);
    } else {
        return theme_pager_next('Newer ›', $limit, $element, $interval, $parameters);
    }
}

function phptemplate_pager_last($text, $limit, $element=0, $parameters=array()) {
    return theme_pager_last('Newest »', $limit, $element, $parameters);
}
```

Almost works, until you travel to the second to last page where (in pager.inc) `theme_pager_next()` delegates to `theme_pager_last()` and this replacement breaks ...

Isn't there a clean way to do this with themeing?  Hopefully better than just copy/pasting `theme_pager()` and replacing strings there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I used this and it works very well.
Put it into template.php

```
function yourTheme_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 10, $element = 0, $parameters = array(), $quantity = 5) {
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;

  // Calculate various markers within this pager piece:
  // Middle is used to "center" pages around the current page.
  $pager_middle = ceil($quantity / 2);
  // current is the page we are currently paged to
  $pager_current = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  // first is the first page listed by this pager piece (re quantity)
  $pager_first = $pager_current - $pager_middle + 1;
  // last is the last page listed by this pager piece (re quantity)
  $pager_last = $pager_current + $quantity - $pager_middle;
  // max is the maximum page number
  $pager_max = $pager_total[$element];
  // End of marker calculations.

  $pager_delim = '';

  // Prepare for generation loop.
  $i = $pager_first;
  if ($pager_last > $pager_max) {
    // Adjust "center" if at end of query.
    $i = $i + ($pager_max - $pager_last);
    $pager_last = $pager_max;
  }
  if ($i <= 0) {
    // Adjust "center" if at start of query.
    $pager_last = $pager_last + (1 - $i);
    $i = 1;
  }
  // End of generation loop preparation.
$li_first_numb = theme('pager_first', (isset($tags[0]) ? $tags[0] : t('1')), $limit, $element, $parameters);
  $li_first = theme('pager_first', (isset($tags[0]) ? $tags[0] : t('<<')), $limit, $element, $parameters);
  $li_previous = theme('pager_previous', (isset($tags[1]) ? $tags[1] : t('<')), $limit, $element, 1, $parameters);
  $li_next = theme('pager_next', (isset($tags[3]) ? $tags[3] : t('>')), $limit, $element, 1, $parameters);
  $li_last = theme('pager_last', (isset($tags[4]) ? $tags[4] : t('>>')), $limit, $element, $parameters);
  $li_last_numb = theme('pager_last', (isset($tags[4]) ? $tags[4] : t($pager_max)), $limit, $element, $parameters);


  if ($pager_total[$element] > 1) {
    if ($li_first) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => 'pager-first',
        'data' => $li_first,
      );
    }
    if ($li_previous) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => 'pager-previous',
        'data' => $li_previous,
      );
    }

    // When there is more than one page, create the pager list.
    if ($i != $pager_max) {
    if ($i > 1) {
        $items[] = array(
          'class' => 'pager-first',
          'data' => $li_first_numb,
        );
      }
      if ($i > 1) {
        $items[] = array(
          'class' => 'pager-ellipsis',
          'data' => '...',
        );
      }
      // Now generate the actual pager piece.
      for (; $i <= $pager_last && $i <= $pager_max; $i++) {
        if ($i < $pager_current) {
          $items[] = array(
            'class' => 'pager-item',
            'data' => theme('pager_previous', $i, $limit, $element, ($pager_current - $i), $parameters).$pager_delim,
          );
        }
        if ($i == $pager_current) {
          $items[] = array(
            'class' => 'pager-current',
            /*'data' => '['.$i.']'.$pager_delim,*/
            'data' => $i,
          );
        }
        if ($i > $pager_current) {
          $items[] = array(
            'class' => 'pager-item',
            'data' => $pager_delim.theme('pager_next', $i, $limit, $element, ($i - $pager_current), $parameters),
          );
        }
      }
      if ($i < $pager_max) {
        $items[] = array(
          'class' => 'pager-ellipses',
          'data' => '...',
        );
      }
      if ($i < $pager_max) {
        $items[] = array(
          'class' => 'pager-max-numb',
          'data' => $li_last_numb,
        );
      }

    }
    // End generation.
    if ($li_next) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => 'pager-next',
        'data' => $li_next,
      );
    }
    if ($li_last) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => 'pager-last',
        'data' => $li_last,
      );
    }
    return theme('item_list', $items, NULL, 'ul', array('class' => 'pager'));
  }
}
```

In this part of the code

```
 $li_first_numb = theme('pager_first', (isset($tags[0]) ? $tags[0] : t('1')), $limit, $element, $parameters);
      $li_first = theme('pager_first', (isset($tags[0]) ? $tags[0] : t('<<')), $limit, $element, $parameters);
      $li_previous = theme('pager_previous', (isset($tags[1]) ? $tags[1] : t('<')), $limit, $element, 1, $parameters);
      $li_next = theme('pager_next', (isset($tags[3]) ? $tags[3] : t('>')), $limit, $element, 1, $parameters);
      $li_last = theme('pager_last', (isset($tags[4]) ? $tags[4] : t('>>')), $limit, $element, $parameters);
```

You can modify first/previous/next/last

Comment: Well, I was hoping to not copy/paste such a large function...  But it's not so bad, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following for a simple version (works in Drupal 7)

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_pager(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($variables['quantity'] > 5) $variables['quantity'] = 5;
  $variables['tags'][0] = '<<';
  $variables['tags'][1] = '<';
  $variables['tags'][3] = '>';
  $variables['tags'][4] = '>>';
}
```

or

```
function THEMENAME_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 10, $element = 0, $parameters = array()) {
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;
  $page_prev = $pager_page_array[$element] - 1;
  $page_curr = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  $page_next = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  if ($pager_total[$element] > 1) {
    $output = '<div class="previous-next">';
    if ($pager_page_array[$element]!=0) $output.= '<a href="?page='.$page_prev.'" class="previous">Previous</a>';
    $output.= '<div class="previous-next-page">Page '.$page_curr.'/'.$pager_total[$element].'</div>';
    if ($page_curr!=$pager_total[$element]) $output.= '<a href="?page='.$page_next.'" class="next">Older blog posts</a>';
    $output.= '</div>';
    return $output;
  }
}
```