# Replace page number with image field value in pager

Tags: 7, views, paging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use a content type’s field as a pager item in Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41138/use-a-content-types-field-as-a-pager-item-in-views)

I created a view of nodes (it shows full node, not its fields) and have a full pager.

Every node has image field and I would like to replace page numbers in pager by these images. It would looks like a previews. Now I have "prev 1 2 3 next" and would like to have "prev image#1 image#2 image3 next".

Is it possible to use field value of node instead of number in pager?

Comment: I know that slideshow with thumbnails could solve this problem but when I choose show node content instead of field the pager option become unavaliable.

Comment: I think this can help you a bit.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32777/change-pager-text/32793#32793

Comment: thank you but the problem is not just to replace the text in pager but to fetch the field_image of every node and show images instead page numbers in pager